# Closed form expression of Bayes Factor

Tags: integral, bayes-factors

**Setting**

Let data $\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where we consider $\sigma^2$ known.

Prior: $\mu \sim N(m_0,  \sigma^2 / n_0)$.

---

**Question**

I'm trying to calculate $A / B$, where

- $A = p(data | \mu = m_0, \sigma^2)$
- $B = \int p(data | \mu, \sigma^2) \,\, p(\mu | m_0, n_0, \sigma^2) \,\, d\mu$

**Can yo help me to obtain the result below?**

---

**Answer**

[image]